# Difference between ALL 1D points in array with python diff()?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, difference

Looking for tips on how one would write a function (or could recommend a function that already exists) that calculates the difference between all entries in the array i.e. an implementation of `diff()` but for all entry combinations in the array not just consecutive pairs.

Here is an example of what I want:

```
# example array
a = [3, 2, 5, 1]
```

Now we want to apply a function which will return the difference between all combinations of entries. Now given that `length(a) == 4` that means that the total number of combinations is, for N = 4; N*(N-1)*0.5 = 6 (if the length of a was 5 then the total number of combinations would be 10 and so on). So the function should return the following for vector `a`:

```
result = some_function(a)
print result
array([-1, 2, -2, 3, -1, -4])
```

So the 'function' would be similar to `pdist` but instead of calculating the Euclidean distance, it should simply calculate the difference between the Cartesian coordinate along one axis e.g. the z-axis if we assume that the entries in `a` are coordinates. As can be noted I need the sign of each difference to understand what side of the axis each point is located.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> a = [3, 2, 5, 1]
>>> [y - x for x, y in it.combinations(a, 2)]
[-1, 2, -2, 3, -1, -4]
```

Comment: Cheers for that. Yeah something like that. But I was wondering if there is some function of numpy or scipy which does it efficiently? I need to calculate the above for several tens of thousands of rows of data, so ideally it should be efficient.

Comment: @Astrid - The vectorized numpy version will calculate each value twice, but it some cases it might still be faster.  Basically, you want the lower triangle of `np.subtract.outer(a, a)`.  wim's answer is likely to be faster in a lot of cases, though.

Comment: Didn't notice the numpy tag at first, and you used list data in your question.  Joe's suggestion is good, and then you can collect the values from the lower triangle using `np.tril_indices`

Answer (score 1):

So I tried out the methods proposed by wim and Joe (and Joe and wim's combined suggestion), and this is what I came up with:

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(10, size=1000)

def cartesian_distance(x):
    return np.subtract.outer(x,x)[np.tril_indices(x.shape[0],k=-1)]

%timeit cartesian_distance(a)
%timeit [y - x for x, y in it.combinations(a, 2)]
```

---

```
10 loops, best of 3: 97.9 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 333 ms per loop
```

For smaller entries:

```
a = np.random.randint(10, size=10)

def cartesian_distance(x):
    return np.subtract.outer(x,x)[np.tril_indices(x.shape[0],k=-1)]

%timeit cartesian_distance(a)
%timeit [y - x for x, y in it.combinations(a, 2)]
```

---

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 78.6 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 40.1 µs per loop
```